# Awesome fonts failed to decode in Meteor+react

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

During my implementation of [`react-widgets`](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/?_k=0i2obt) in Meteor+React,
I am able to get the datetime object. But somehow the [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/) are not loaded correctly, so the datetime object looks now like:

[image]

The console gives me the following warning:

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/rw-widgets.ttf?v=4.1.0
>
> OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

**current implementation**

I imported the required css file in main.js:

```
import 'react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css';
```

In my app I imported the date time picker, nothing fancy here.

```
import { DateTimePicker } from 'react-widgets';
...
<DateTimePicker
    ref="startedAt"
    format={'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'}
    timeFormat={'HH:mm'}
    step={1}
    className='form-control'
    defaultValue={startDate}
    culture='en' />
```

So probably I forgot something straight forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a public folder in your project folder, which has client, server, imports and other folders.
2. copy fonts and img folders from "your project folder/node_modules/react-widgets/dist/" to your public folders above. After restart of your server, you should not see the warnings you have mentioned.

Comment: I also had to put this in my scss file: $rw-font-path: "~/fonts"; otherwise the browser looked for the fonts in the current route.